I must fit sigmoid functions to two types of datasets (6 datasets each) with r^2 values, then plot derivatives of the fit functions. I get errors
The code worked for one of the datasets but not the other. I receive errors (shown at the bottom of my provided code).
You can see that I have two commented out data sections by type: One for work density, one for strain.
I am trying to plot the 6 datasets, present in each type, as independent curves against the x data.
I don't need all 12 plotted- I am just exchanging the strain data for the work density data as I need.
I am unable to succeed. I am sure the code is correct and should work but something is too calculation-intensive...?
The expected results: A plot of the fitting functions (logistic sigmoid) for 6 datasets, then a subplot included of the derivative of their theoretical curves. Returned values of R^2 squared values (I cannot use mean-squared error).
# This code produces a 99-100% fitness of fit to Normal Fibril strain v. temperature data, or, work      
density v. temperature data, using a technical 
# 4-parameter logistic sigmoid function, but with the centroid parameter pre-defined at 77.5 degrees  
Celsius on the x-axis. This 'b' parameter is 
# left undefined for the derivative function. 

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# 1. Normal Fibrils user dataset: 
x_data = np.array([25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115,      
120, 125, 130]) 
y_data50 = np.array([0, 0, 0.250155, 1.00062, 1.751085, 2.50155, 3.252015, 4.752945, 6.253875, 
7.00434, 8.50527, 10.756665, 13.00806, 16.260075, 18.51147, 19.261935, 19.51209, 19.762245, 19.762245, 
20.0124, 20.0124, 20.0124]) 
y_data100 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1.98162, 3.467835, 5.94486, 7.431075, 9.9081, 13.87134, 16.348365,  
18.82539, 22.78863, 28.73349, 34.67835, 40.62321, 42.60483, 43.59564, 44.58645, 45.081855, 45.081855, 
45.081855])
y_data150 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 2.221965, 4.44393, 7.40655, 10.36917, 13.33179, 17.035065, 22.21965,  
25.18227, 31.10751, 37.03275, 44.4393, 51.84585, 62.21502, 68.14026, 71.10288, 74.0655, 75.54681, 
75.54681])
y_data200 = np.array([0, 0, 0, -1.97181, -1.97181, 3.94362, 7.88724, 13.80267, 18.732195, 25.63353,  
31.54896, 39.4362, 45.35163, 51.26706, 62.112015, 73.942875, 86.75964, 96.61869, 106.47774, 108.44955, 
110.42136, 112.39317])
y_data250 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 2.46231, 4.92462, 9.84924, 14.77386, 20.929635, 27.08541, 34.47234, 
41.85927, 54.17082, 64.02006, 73.8693, 86.18085, 103.41702, 118.19088, 130.50243, 137.88936,  
140.35167, 142.81398, 145.27629])
y_data300 = np.array([0, 0, 1.476405, 2.95281, 4.429215, 7.382025, 13.287645, 20.66967, 28.051695,  
38.38653, 51.674175, 67.91463, 82.67868, 100.39554, 121.06521, 137.305665, 150.59331, 157.975335,  
165.35736, 168.31017, 171.26298, 171.26298])

# Normal Fibrils' Work Density Data: 
# m(w) = 50m(f): y_data50 = np.array([0, 0, 0.250155, 1.00062, 1.751085, 2.50155, 3.252015, 4.752945,   
6.253875, 7.00434, 8.50527, 10.756665, 13.00806, 16.260075, 18.51147, 19.261935, 19.51209, 19.762245, 
19.762245, 20.0124, 20.0124, 20.0124]) 
# m(w) = 100m(f): y_data100 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1.98162, 3.467835, 5.94486, 7.431075, 9.9081, 
13.87134, 16.348365, 18.82539, 22.78863, 28.73349, 34.67835, 40.62321, 42.60483, 43.59564, 44.58645, 
45.081855, 45.081855, 45.081855])
# m(w) = 150m(f): y_data150 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 2.221965, 4.44393, 7.40655, 10.36917, 13.33179,  
17.035065, 22.21965, 25.18227, 31.10751, 37.03275, 44.4393, 51.84585, 62.21502, 68.14026, 71.10288, 
74.0655, 75.54681, 75.54681])
# m(w) = 200m(f): y_data200 = np.array([0, 0, 0, -1.97181, -1.97181, 3.94362, 7.88724, 13.80267, 
18.732195, 25.63353, 31.54896, 39.4362, 45.35163, 51.26706, 62.112015, 73.942875, 86.75964, 96.61869, 
106.47774, 108.44955, 110.42136, 112.39317])
# m(w) = 250m(f): y_data250 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 2.46231, 4.92462, 9.84924, 14.77386, 20.929635, 
27.08541, 34.47234, 41.85927, 54.17082, 64.02006, 73.8693, 86.18085, 103.41702, 118.19088, 130.50243, 
137.88936, 140.35167, 142.81398, 145.27629])
# m(w) = 300m(f): y_data300 = np.array([0, 0, 1.476405, 2.95281, 4.429215, 7.382025, 13.287645,  
20.66967, 28.051695, 38.38653, 51.674175, 67.91463, 82.67868, 100.39554, 121.06521, 137.305665, 
150.59331, 157.975335, 165.35736, 168.31017, 171.26298, 171.26298])

# Normal Fibrils' Strain Data: 
# x_data = np.array([25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 
120, 125, 130])
# m(w) = 50m(f): y_data50 = np.array([0, 0, 0.00617284, 0.024691358, 0.043209877, 0.061728395, 
0.080246914, 0.117283951, 0.154320988, 0.172839506, 0.209876543, 0.265432099, 0.320987654, 
0.401234568, 0.456790123, 0.475308642, 0.481481481, 0.487654321, 0.487654321, 0.49382716, 0.49382716, 
0.49382716])
# m(w) = 100m(f): y_data100 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.021978022, 0.038461538, 0.065934066, 
0.082417582, 0.10989011, 0.153846154, 0.181318681, 0.208791209, 0.252747253, 0.318681319, 0.384615385, 
0.450549451, 0.472527473, 0.483516484, 0.494505495, 0.5])
# m(w) = 150m(f): y_data150 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0.015151515, 0.03030303, 0.050505051, 0.070707071, 
0.090909091, 0.116161616, 0.151515152, 0.171717172, 0.212121212, 0.252525253, 0.303030303, 
0.353535354, 0.424242424, 0.464646465, 0.484848485, 0.505050505, 0.515151515, 0.515151515])
# m(w) = 200m(f): y_data200 = np.array([0, 0, 0, -0.009345794, -0.009345794, 0.018691589, 0.037383178,     
0.065420561, 0.088785047, 0.121495327, 0.14953271, 0.186915888, 0.214953271, 0.242990654, 0.294392523,  
0.35046729, 0.411214953, 0.457943925, 0.504672897, 0.514018692, 0.523364486, 0.53271028])
# m(w) = 250m(f): y_data250 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0.009090909, 0.018181818, 0.036363636, 0.054545455,  
0.077272727, 0.1, 0.127272727, 0.154545455, 0.2, 0.236363636, 0.272727273, 0.318181818, 0.381818182, 
0.436363636, 0.481818182, 0.509090909, 0.518181818, 0.527272727, 0.536363636])
# m(w) = 300m(f): y_data300 = np.array([0, 0, 0.004504505, 0.009009009, 0.013513514, 0.022522523, 
0.040540541, 0.063063063, 0.085585586, 0.117117117, 0.157657658, 0.207207207, 0.252252252, 
0.306306306, 0.369369369, 0.418918919, 0.459459459, 0.481981982, 0.504504505, 0.513513514, 
0.522522523, 0.522522523])

# 2. Four-parameter sigmoid fitting function: 
def sigmoid(x, a, b, c, U):
    return (U / (1 + np.exp(-c * (x - b))))**a

# 3. Sigmoid derivative function: 
def sigmoid_derivative(x, a, b, c, U):
    return (a * U * np.exp(-c * (x - b)) * (1 + np.exp(-c * (x - b)))**(-a - 1) * c) / (1 + np.exp(-c  
* (x - b)))**(2*a)

# 4. Initial guess for the fitting parameters: 
initial_guess = [1, 77.5, 0.1, 0.5]

# 5. Fit the sigmoid function to each dataset and calculate R-squared value: 
popt50, _ = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data50, p0=initial_guess)
y_pred50 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt50)
r_squared_50 = r2_score(y_data50, y_pred50)

popt100, _ = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data100, p0=initial_guess)
y_pred100 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt100)
r_squared_100 = r2_score(y_data100, y_pred100)

popt150, _ = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data150, p0=initial_guess)
y_pred150 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt150)
r_squared_150 = r2_score(y_data150, y_pred150)

popt200, _ = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data200, p0=initial_guess)
y_pred200 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt200)
r_squared_200 = r2_score(y_data200, y_pred200)

popt250, _ = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data250, p0=initial_guess)
y_pred250 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt250)
r_squared_250 = r2_score(y_data250, y_pred250)

popt300, _ = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data300, p0=initial_guess)
y_pred300 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt300)
r_squared_300 = r2_score(y_data300, y_pred300)

# 6. Generate x values for the fitted curve: 
x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 1000)

# 7. Calculate the y values using the fitted parameters for each dataset: 
y_fit50 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt50)
y_fit100 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt100)
y_fit150 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt150)
y_fit200 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt200)
y_fit250 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt250)
y_fit300 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt300)

# 8. Calculate the derivatives of each fitted curve: 
dy_dx_fit50 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt50)
dy_dx_fit100 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt100)
dy_dx_fit150 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt150)
dy_dx_fit200 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt200)
dy_dx_fit250 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt250)
dy_dx_fit300 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt300)

# 9. Plotting: 
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

# 10. Plot sigmoid fits: 
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) 
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit300, '-', color = 'black', label = f'm(w) = 300m(f)|(R^2={r_squared_300:.2f})') 
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit250, '-', color = 'purple', label = f'm(w) = 250m(f)|(R^2={r_squared_250:.2f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit200, '-', color = 'red', label = f'm(w) = 200m(f)|(R^2={r_squared_200:.2f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit150, '-', color = 'orange', label = f'm(w) = 150m(f)|(R^2={r_squared_150:.2f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit100, '-', color = 'gold', label = f'm(w) = 100m(f)|(R^2={r_squared_100:.2f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit50, '-', color = 'green', label = f'm(w) = 50m(f)|(R^2={r_squared_50:.2f})')

plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)') 
plt.ylabel('Work Density WD') 
plt.title('Sigmoidal Fit to Normal Fibril Data [WD v. T]') 
#plt.ylabel('Strain ε, (Δl/$\mathregular{l_{0}}$)') 
#plt.title('Sigmoidal Fit to Normal Fibril Data [ε v. T]') 
plt.legend() 
plt.grid(True)

# 11. Plot derivatives: 
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit300, '--', color = 'black', label = 'Rate for m(w) = 300m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit250, '--', color = 'purple', label = 'Rate for m(w) = 250m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit200, '--', color = 'red', label = 'Rate for m(w) = 200m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit150, '--', color = 'orange', label = 'Rate for m(w) = 150m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit100, '--', color = 'gold', label = 'Rate for m(w) = 100m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit50, '--', color = 'green', label='Rate for m(w) = 50m(f)')

plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)') 
plt.ylabel('ΔWD/ΔT, (Nm/kg°C)')
#plt.ylabel('Δε/ΔT, ((Δl/$\mathregular{l_{0}}$)/°C)')
plt.title('Contraction Rate')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show() 

The errors:

'Runtime Warning: divide by zero encountered in power'
'Runtime Warning: invalid value encountered in power'
'Optimize Warning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated.'
'line 52, in <module> popt100, _ ..... line 982, in curve_fit raise Runtime Error("Optimal parameters not found:)'
'Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000.'


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# 1. User datasets: 
x_data = np.array([25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130])
y_dataWD50 = np.array([0, 0, 0.250155, 1.00062, 1.751085, 2.50155, 3.252015, 4.752945, 6.253875, 7.00434, 8.50527, 10.756665, 13.00806, 16.260075, 18.51147, 19.261935, 19.51209, 19.762245, 19.762245, 20.0124, 20.0124, 20.0124]) 
y_dataWD100 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1.98162, 3.467835, 5.94486, 7.431075, 9.9081, 13.87134, 16.348365, 18.82539, 22.78863, 28.73349, 34.67835, 40.62321, 42.60483, 43.59564, 44.58645, 45.081855, 45.081855, 45.081855])
y_dataWD150 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 2.221965, 4.44393, 7.40655, 10.36917, 13.33179, 17.035065, 22.21965, 25.18227, 31.10751, 37.03275, 44.4393, 51.84585, 62.21502, 68.14026, 71.10288, 74.0655, 75.54681, 75.54681])
y_dataWD200 = np.array([0, 0, 0, -1.97181, -1.97181, 3.94362, 7.88724, 13.80267, 18.732195, 25.63353, 31.54896, 39.4362, 45.35163, 51.26706, 62.112015, 73.942875, 86.75964, 96.61869, 106.47774, 108.44955, 110.42136, 112.39317])
y_dataWD250 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 2.46231, 4.92462, 9.84924, 14.77386, 20.929635, 27.08541, 34.47234, 41.85927, 54.17082, 64.02006, 73.8693, 86.18085, 103.41702, 118.19088, 130.50243, 137.88936, 140.35167, 142.81398, 145.27629])
y_dataWD300 = np.array([0, 0, 1.476405, 2.95281, 4.429215, 7.382025, 13.287645, 20.66967, 28.051695, 38.38653, 51.674175, 67.91463, 82.67868, 100.39554, 121.06521, 137.305665, 150.59331, 157.975335, 165.35736, 168.31017, 171.26298, 171.26298])

# (A.) Normal Fibrils' Work Density Data: 
# m(w) = 50m(f): y_data50 = np.array([0, 0, 0.250155, 1.00062, 1.751085, 2.50155, 3.252015, 4.752945, 6.253875, 7.00434, 8.50527, 10.756665, 13.00806, 16.260075, 18.51147, 19.261935, 19.51209, 19.762245, 19.762245, 20.0124, 20.0124, 20.0124]) 
# m(w) = 100m(f): y_data100 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1.98162, 3.467835, 5.94486, 7.431075, 9.9081, 13.87134, 16.348365, 18.82539, 22.78863, 28.73349, 34.67835, 40.62321, 42.60483, 43.59564, 44.58645, 45.081855, 45.081855, 45.081855])
# m(w) = 150m(f): y_data150 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 2.221965, 4.44393, 7.40655, 10.36917, 13.33179, 17.035065, 22.21965, 25.18227, 31.10751, 37.03275, 44.4393, 51.84585, 62.21502, 68.14026, 71.10288, 74.0655, 75.54681, 75.54681])
# m(w) = 200m(f): y_data200 = np.array([0, 0, 0, -1.97181, -1.97181, 3.94362, 7.88724, 13.80267, 18.732195, 25.63353, 31.54896, 39.4362, 45.35163, 51.26706, 62.112015, 73.942875, 86.75964, 96.61869, 106.47774, 108.44955, 110.42136, 112.39317])
# m(w) = 250m(f): y_data250 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 2.46231, 4.92462, 9.84924, 14.77386, 20.929635, 27.08541, 34.47234, 41.85927, 54.17082, 64.02006, 73.8693, 86.18085, 103.41702, 118.19088, 130.50243, 137.88936, 140.35167, 142.81398, 145.27629])
# m(w) = 300m(f): y_data300 = np.array([0, 0, 1.476405, 2.95281, 4.429215, 7.382025, 13.287645, 20.66967, 28.051695, 38.38653, 51.674175, 67.91463, 82.67868, 100.39554, 121.06521, 137.305665, 150.59331, 157.975335, 165.35736, 168.31017, 171.26298, 171.26298])

# (B.) Normal Fibrils' Strain Data: 
# x_data = np.array([25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130])
# m(w) = 50m(f): y_data50 = np.array([0, 0, 0.00617284, 0.024691358, 0.043209877, 0.061728395, 0.080246914, 0.117283951, 0.154320988, 0.172839506, 0.209876543, 0.265432099, 0.320987654, 0.401234568, 0.456790123, 0.475308642, 0.481481481, 0.487654321, 0.487654321, 0.49382716, 0.49382716, 0.49382716])
# m(w) = 100m(f): y_data100 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.021978022, 0.038461538, 0.065934066, 0.082417582, 0.10989011, 0.153846154, 0.181318681, 0.208791209, 0.252747253, 0.318681319, 0.384615385, 0.450549451, 0.472527473, 0.483516484, 0.494505495, 0.5])
# m(w) = 150m(f): y_data150 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0.015151515, 0.03030303, 0.050505051, 0.070707071, 0.090909091, 0.116161616, 0.151515152, 0.171717172, 0.212121212, 0.252525253, 0.303030303, 0.353535354, 0.424242424, 0.464646465, 0.484848485, 0.505050505, 0.515151515, 0.515151515])
# m(w) = 200m(f): y_data200 = np.array([0, 0, 0, -0.009345794, -0.009345794, 0.018691589, 0.037383178, 0.065420561, 0.088785047, 0.121495327, 0.14953271, 0.186915888, 0.214953271, 0.242990654, 0.294392523, 0.35046729, 0.411214953, 0.457943925, 0.504672897, 0.514018692, 0.523364486, 0.53271028])
# m(w) = 250m(f): y_data250 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0.009090909, 0.018181818, 0.036363636, 0.054545455, 0.077272727, 0.1, 0.127272727, 0.154545455, 0.2, 0.236363636, 0.272727273, 0.318181818, 0.381818182, 0.436363636, 0.481818182, 0.509090909, 0.518181818, 0.527272727, 0.536363636])
# m(w) = 300m(f): y_data300 = np.array([0, 0, 0.004504505, 0.009009009, 0.013513514, 0.022522523, 0.040540541, 0.063063063, 0.085585586, 0.117117117, 0.157657658, 0.207207207, 0.252252252, 0.306306306, 0.369369369, 0.418918919, 0.459459459, 0.481981982, 0.504504505, 0.513513514, 0.522522523, 0.522522523])

# 2. Sigmoid function defined: 
def sigmoid(x, U, k, x0, a):
    return U / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - x0)))**a

# 3. Initial guesses for calculating fitting parameters: 
p0_WD50 = [max(y_dataWD50), -0.1, 77.5, 1.0] 
p0_WD100 = [max(y_dataWD100), -0.1, 77.5, 1.0] 
p0_WD150 = [max(y_dataWD150), -0.1, 77.5, 1.0] 
p0_WD200 = [max(y_dataWD200), -0.1, 77.5, 1.0] 
p0_WD250 = [max(y_dataWD250), -0.1, 77.5, 1.0] 
p0_WD300 = [max(y_dataWD300), -0.1, 77.5, 1.0] 

# 3b. Derivative of 'sigmoid' defined: 
def sigmoid_derivative(x, U, k, x0, a):
    exp_term = np.exp(-k * (x - x0))
    sigmoid_term = (1 + exp_term) ** (-k)
    return a * (U / (1 + exp_term)) ** (a - 1) * U * k * exp_term * sigmoid_term

# 4. Sigmoid fitting operation: 
x_fit = np.linspace(25, 130, 100) 

# 4a. Estimated parameters for fitting & R^2 fittness of fit values: 
# (i.) m(w) = 50m(f) 
poptWD50, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_dataWD50, p0_WD50, maxfev = 10000) 
y_estWD50 = sigmoid(x_data, *poptWD50) 
r_squaredWD50 = r2_score(y_dataWD50, y_estWD50) 
print(f"R^2 Value: {r_squaredWD50:.3f}")  

# (ii.) m(w) = 100m(f) 
poptWD100, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_dataWD100, p0_WD100, maxfev = 10000) 
y_estWD100 = sigmoid(x_data, *poptWD100) 
r_squaredWD100 = r2_score(y_dataWD100, y_estWD100) 
print(f"R^2 Value: {r_squaredWD100:.3f}")  

# (iii.) m(w) = 150m(f) 
poptWD150, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_dataWD150, p0_WD150, maxfev = 10000) 
y_estWD150 = sigmoid(x_data, *poptWD150) 
r_squaredWD150 = r2_score(y_dataWD150, y_estWD150) 
print(f"R^2 Value: {r_squaredWD100:.3f}")  

# (iv.) m(w) = 200m(f) 
poptWD200, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_dataWD200, p0_WD200, maxfev = 10000) 
y_estWD200 = sigmoid(x_data, *poptWD200) 
r_squaredWD200 = r2_score(y_dataWD200, y_estWD200) 
print(f"R^2 Value: {r_squaredWD200:.3f}")  

# (v.) m(w) = 250m(f) 
poptWD250, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_dataWD250, p0_WD250, maxfev = 10000) 
y_estWD250 = sigmoid(x_data, *poptWD250) 
r_squaredWD250 = r2_score(y_dataWD250, y_estWD250) 
print(f"R^2 Value: {r_squaredWD250:.3f}")  

# (vi.) m(w) = 300m(f) 
poptWD300, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_dataWD300, p0_WD300, maxfev = 10000) 
y_estWD300 = sigmoid(x_data, *poptWD300) 
r_squaredWD300 = r2_score(y_dataWD300, y_estWD300) 
print(f"R^2 Value: {r_squaredWD300:.3f}")  

# 4b. Calculation of Sigmoid Fit y-values & derivative y-values using the estimated parameters per dataset: 
# (i.) [m(w) = 50m(f)]: 
y_fitWD50 = sigmoid(x_fit, *poptWD50) 
dy_dx_fitWD50 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *poptWD50) 
# (ii.) [m(w) = 100m(f)]: 
y_fitWD100 = sigmoid(x_fit, *poptWD100) 
dy_dx_fitWD100 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *poptWD100) 
# (iii.) [m(w) = 150m(f)]: 
y_fitWD150 = sigmoid(x_fit, *poptWD150) 
dy_dx_fitWD150 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *poptWD150) 
# (iv.) [m(w) = 200m(f)]: 
y_fitWD200 = sigmoid(x_fit, *poptWD200) 
dy_dx_fitWD200 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *poptWD200) 
# (v.) [m(w) = 250m(f)]: 
y_fitWD250 = sigmoid(x_fit, *poptWD250) 
dy_dx_fitWD250 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *poptWD250) 
# (vi.) [m(w) = 300m(f)]: 
y_fitWD300 = sigmoid(x_fit, *poptWD300) 
dy_dx_fitWD300 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *poptWD300) 

# 6. Print the logistic sigmoid fitting parameters: 
print("Estimated Parameters:", poptWD50) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", poptWD100) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", poptWD150) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", poptWD200) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", poptWD250) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", poptWD300) 

# 7. Plot data, logistic sigmoid function fit & the derivative: 
plt.figure(figsize = (9, 10))

# 7a. Datas' & Sigmoid Fits' subplot: 
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1) 

plt.plot(x_fit, y_fitWD50, '-', color = 'green', label=f'm(w) = 50m(f) (R^2 Value = {r_squaredWD50:.3f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fitWD100, '-', color = 'yellow', label=f'm(w) = 100m(f) (R^2 Value = {r_squaredWD100:.3f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fitWD150, '-', color = 'gold', label=f'm(w) = 150m(f) (R^2 Value = {r_squaredWD150:.3f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fitWD200, '-', color = 'darkorange', label=f'm(w) = 200m(f) (R^2 Value = {r_squaredWD200:.3f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fitWD250, '-', color = 'red', label=f'm(w) = 250m(f) (R^2 Value = {r_squaredWD250:.3f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fitWD300, '-', color = 'purple', label=f'm(w) = 300m(f) (R^2 Value = {r_squaredWD300:.3f})') 

plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)') 
plt.ylabel('Work Density ' + '$\it{WD}$ ' + '(Nm/kg)')
plt.title('$\mathregular{[l_{i}}$ = $\mathregular{L_{0}]}$ '+ 'Logistic Sigmoidal Fit to Work Density Data') 
plt.legend() 
plt.grid(True) 

# 7b. Derivatives of the sigmoids' subplot: 
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2) 

plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fitWD50, '--', color = 'green', label='Rate for m(w) = 50m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fitWD100, '--', color = 'yellow', label='Rate for m(w) = 100m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fitWD150, '--', color = 'gold', label='Rate for m(w) = 150m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fitWD200, '--', color = 'darkorange', label='Rate for m(w) = 200m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fitWD250, '--', color = 'red', label='Rate for m(w) = 250m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fitWD300, '--', color = 'purple', label='Rate for m(w) = 300m(f)') 
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)') 
plt.ylabel('Rate of Change, ' + '$\it{ΔWD/ΔT}$ ' + '(Nm/kg°C)')
plt.legend() 
plt.title('Work Density Rates (Derivative of Characteristic Sigmoids)') 

plt.show() 


The problem you are facing come from the sigmoid function trying to aise negative numbers to a fractional power, which results in a complex number in Python. I suggest adjusting the bounds for your parameters to ensure that all values fed into the power function are positive, modify the initial guesses for the parameters to ensure they are more likely to lead to a valid solution and add Bounds to fit the curve.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score


x_data = np.array([25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130])

y_datasets = {
    '50': np.array([0, 0, 0.250155, 1.00062, 1.751085, 2.50155, 3.252015, 4.752945, 6.253875, 
                    7.00434, 8.50527, 10.756665, 13.00806, 16.260075, 18.51147, 19.261935, 19.51209, 19.762245, 19.762245, 
                    20.0124, 20.0124, 20.0124]), 
    '100': np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1.98162, 3.467835, 5.94486, 7.431075, 9.9081, 13.87134, 16.348365,  
                     18.82539, 22.78863, 28.73349, 34.67835, 40.62321, 42.60483, 43.59564, 44.58645, 45.081855, 45.081855, 
                     45.081855]),
    '150': np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 2.221965, 4.44393, 7.40655, 10.36917, 13.33179, 17.035065, 22.21965,  
                     25.18227, 31.10751, 37.03275, 44.4393, 51.84585, 62.21502, 68.14026, 71.10288, 74.0655, 75.54681, 
                     75.54681]),
    '200': np.array([0, 0, 0, -1.97181, -1.97181, 3.94362, 7.88724, 13.80267, 18.732195, 25.63353,  
                     31.54896, 39.4362, 45.35163, 51.26706, 62.112015, 73.942875, 86.75964, 96.61869, 106.47774, 108.44955, 
                     110.42136, 112.39317]),
    '250': np.array([0, 0, 0, 2.46231, 4.92462, 9.84924, 14.77386, 20.929635, 27.08541, 34.47234, 
                     41.85927, 54.17082, 64.02006, 73.8693, 86.18085, 103.41702, 118.19088, 130.50243, 137.88936,  
                     140.35167, 142.81398, 145.27629]),
    '300': np.array([0, 0, 1.476405, 2.95281, 4.429215, 7.382025, 13.287645, 20.66967, 28.051695,  
                     38.38653, 51.674175, 67.91463, 82.67868, 100.39554, 121.06521, 137.305665, 150.59331, 157.975335,  
                     165.35736, 168.31017, 171.26298, 171.26298])
}

def sigmoid(x, a, c, U):
    b = 77.5  
    base = U / (1 + np.exp(-c * (x - b)))
    return np.maximum(base, 0) ** a  

def sigmoid_derivative(x, a, c, U):
    b = 77.5
    e = np.exp(-c * (x - b))
    base = U / (1 + e)
    return (a * c * e * base ** (a - 1)) / (1 + e) ** a

bounds = ([0, 0, 0], [np.inf, 1, np.inf])  
fit_results = {}
for key, y_data in y_datasets.items():
    try:
        popt, _ = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data, p0=[1, 0.1, max(y_data)], bounds=bounds, maxfev=5000)
        y_pred = sigmoid(x_data, *popt)
        r_squared = r2_score(y_data, y_pred)
        fit_results[key] = (popt, r_squared)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fitting dataset {key}: {e}")

x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 1000)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
colors = ['green', 'gold', 'orange', 'red', 'purple', 'black']
for i, (key, (popt, r_squared)) in enumerate(fit_results.items()):
    y_fit = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt)
    plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, '-', color=colors[i], label=f'm(w) = {key}m(f) | R^2={r_squared:.2f}')

plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.ylabel('Work Density or Strain')
plt.title('Sigmoidal Fit to Data')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
for i, (key, (popt, _)) in enumerate(fit_results.items()):
    dy_dx_fit = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt)
    plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit, '--', color=colors[i], label=f'Rate for m(w) = {key}m(f)')

plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.ylabel('Rate of Change')
plt.title('Derivative of Sigmoidal Fit')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

This solves the problem and gives


Hi there Serge, this was very helpful- I have learned now from your answer the possibility of defining the bounds more aptly for the purpose. I'll try to implement this, yeah. There are other scripts I have for a variety of datasets, so I'll see how I can adjust the way I've coded those, too. I do have a question, though: It seems that the m(w) = 50m(f) derivative didn't plot correctly. How does one adjust that?

@PuppyLord Glad it helped. I think the only problem is the resolution of the graph. Maybe if you change the plot range.
Happy coding!

Hi Serge, kindest apologies to bother but I have been trying to amend the code to solve that issue. I don't think the issue is the resolution, since the green fit is within the same order of magnitude as others. Haven't been able to fix that.
Also, I've been more fundamentally trying to remove the precondition that b = 77.5, as it defines a centroid which doesn't fit all the datasets. So, I thought about having a fitting parameter 'b' that is also guessed by the code. I added in 'b' into the sigmoid function and derivative function parameters, removed the 'b = 77.5', and I get blank plots

I think that the issue is that the max(y_data) specification for popt is defines all the 6 datasets by the highest y-value for them all, not with respect to the particular curve being plotted. That means, the max(y_data) found in 'm(w) = 300m(f)' is too high to resolve the curve for the 'm(w) = 50m(f)' plot. It would also suggest that the other derivative plots are therefore at incorrect magnitudes?

@PuppyLord Does my update make any sense to you?

Hmm, I'm actually quite intrigued. No sir, still a bit confused. I think from analysis, I'm confused why removing the guess for 'b = 77.5' causes a complete derivative failure.
I have something interesting: I tried to see if I could do this with my "convoluted" older script (I have added this as an answer for your consideration). I removed the 'b' parameter (which is called "x0") and I got the exact same plot as above, from your more eloquent code we were discussing.
When adding 'x0 = 77.5', I get a crazy series of derivative plots.
I did use unique max(y_data) successfully, though

@PuppyLord I removed the parametrization and will look into that tomorrow.

I would greatly appreciate that, sir. Thanks a million for the kind help!

Don't call me sir, please.

Update, if I remove 'a' param, I get perfect plots.
If you replace in my answer w/the following:
def sigmoid(x, U, k, x0):
return U / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - x0)))
p0_WD50 = [max(y_dataWD50), -0.1, 77.5]
p0_WD100 = [max(y_dataWD100), -0.1, 77.5]
p0_WD150 = [max(y_dataWD150), -0.1, 77.5]
p0_WD200 = [max(y_dataWD200), -0.1, 77.5]
p0_WD250 = [max(y_dataWD250), -0.1, 77.5]
p0_WD300 = [max(y_dataWD300), -0.1, 77.5]
def sigmoid_derivative(x, U, k, x0):
exp_term = np.exp(-k * (x - x0))
sigmoid_term = (1 + exp_term) ** 2
return U * k * exp_term / sigmoid_term
